# ssh connection issue,getting error message and disappears some times

Tags: ssh, dns, switch, spoofing

```
(base) jecc@sajanraj:~$ ssh odin

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@       WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The ECDSA host key for odin has changed,
and the key for the corresponding IP address 192.168.5.250
is unknown. This could either mean that
DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host
and its host key have changed at the same time.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:mPyyUSVnEvMD4WxMzZWhufbmoJUEY7+DfziKnOpsbsM.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/jecc/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/jecc/.ssh/known_hosts:7
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/jecc/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "odin"
ECDSA host key for odin has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

Already tried to eliminate ssh keys and regenerate it, no change.

Comment: What were you regenerating exactly? If this is on a local subnet, could you test `arping -b -I eth0 192.168.5.250`, see if it always reports the same MAC address?

Comment: Did you regenerate your own ssh key pair or did you clean up the `known_hosts`?

Comment: I got different mac address while arping. What does that means?

Comment: Unicast reply from 192.168.5.250 [D4:3D:7E:65:6D:B1]  1.028ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.5.250 [00:E0:32:11:01:3E]  1.087ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.5.250 [D4:3D:7E:65:6D:B1]  1.012ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.5.250 [00:E0:32:11:01:3E]  1.071ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.5.250 [D4:3D:7E:65:6D:B1]  0.937ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.5.250 [00:E0:32:11:01:3E]  0.988ms
@grawity

Comment: Yeah, you have an IP address conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *two devices* trying to use the same IP address on the same subnet. (As arping shows, their MAC addresses are `00:E0:32:11:01:3E` and `D4:3D:7E:65:6D:B1`.)

That means sometimes you end up connecting to one device and sometimes to the other (depending on which happens to answer the ARP requests first), and naturally they have different SSH hostkeys and cause the mismatch alert.

If they're both legitimate devices, reconfigure one of them to use a different IP address.

(However, this *may* also indicate something malicious going on – exactly the sort of stuff that SSH's known_hosts checking is meant to protect you from.)